# django: populate django models from xml files

Tags: xml, django-models

Is there any good packages that would read the xml files and generate django models? For eg if this is my xml file

```
 <address>
    <street>8th Street</street>
    <city>Saskatoon</city>
    <province>SK</province>
    <country>Canada</country>
</address>
```

Then I want my models to be generated something like this and the data inside the tags should be inserted into database.

```
class Address(Model): 

   id =     DecimalField() 
   street = CharField() 
   city =   CharField() 
   province =  CharField() 
   country = CharField()
```

Is there any package that can handle this?

Comment: how should this program know what type of the column should he create from the XML you posted here?

Comment: ya ur rite. Am not sure how that can be done

Answer (score 0):

I really can't recommend any package (I think it possible to write your own), but for defining types of your fields (e.g. string, decimal, date and so on) you can use XSD along with your XML.

So you read xml root element (in case you have one model in xml file) and create class definition for it. Then read all child elements one by one and look in schema for their type and make type adjustments. So on input you have xml and xsd files and on output you can generate text file with python code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested, have a look at [xml_models](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xml_models/0.5.3). It uses xpath and it is compatible with [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library which works pretty well to parse xml.

I have also found (but haven't tried) [django-xmlmapping](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-xmlmapping).